# How can I paste/move selection at specific exact coordinates?

Tags: gimp

I'd like to paste (or move) rectangular selection at exact cordinates, lets say: top left corner at 100,50. I'm clicking and googling for a while but found nothing.
I was hoping for simple dialog box where I can put these values manually.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Rectangle Select tool to make a selection, then change the position or size by typing in the values you want in the Tool Options.

If you can't see the tool options, click *Windows > Dockable Dialogs > Tool Options*

[image]